# Whats the use of logging into seperate logs if you can't map back effectively?

Tags: logging

I have recently come across possibly what is the most silly implementation of application logging, the developers actually separated logs into validation log files + business logic log files.

For a normal flow for example, the user would purchase some plans, and this goes through some kind of validation, then it gets processed (saved into database for example).

Therefore with the separated logs, it goes..

Go into business.log to look for sequence of events, following, jump into validation.log to look for validation logs pertaining to the user, then jump back to business.log to look for the continuation.

To make matters worse, there is no definite way to map between the logs other than to guess the timestamp, and perhaps the input values (name) that was passed in between.

Therefore when debugging production bugs, it becomes quite messy to toggle between these two files.

The issue is, there are many users and transactions going on at the same time. When questioning the developers over the intend of doing so, the reply was that so the logs were properly segmented. I find this reason quite ridiculous, has anyone come across some references for effective logging? Or does anyone find this way of logging quite normal in enterprises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO there are valid reasons for separating logs.  Perhaps one contains sensitive information.  Maybe one is written much more often and is rarely used.  Maybe one can be toggled on/off for simplicity or security purposes.

Regardless of the reason, logging a transaction ID or user ID with each message would definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

If the logs are properly timestamped, it makes no difference. You could easily combine them into a single file, if needed. If they're not timestamped to enough detail that you can combine them, then I agree with you that it's ridiculous. You need to be able to work out the sequence of events.

Frankly, log files need to catch up. They should be stored in a database with a flexible query language like SQL. You can trivially convert the database into one or more files, as needed, for people who still want them that way.

Comment: I agree with you, but what if there were just so many transactions going on that, for a second, there could be validation logs for 10 users interweaving and going on at the same time?

Comment: I don't see how that's easier or harder if it's in two logs or one log, assuming you can combine the logs by timestamp if desired. You can't really separate logs by user in a file, you'd have too many files. That's another benefit of a DB, you can separate by user in a DB.

Comment: David, its definitely easier that if the logs are contained in a file, then the sequence of event would be quite sequential for tracing purposes, if you get me.

Comment: If they're timestamped (or sequenced), they can trivially be combined from multiple files. I agree that if they don't provide enough information for you to easily determine the order of dependent events logged to separate files, then the logging is broken.